# Where can I download Windows 7 iso

Tags: windows, msdn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

Hello I've get a key for "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional with Service Pack 1 64-bit" as a student. And microsoft site says me to download .exe file, that would install download .iso on my computer. But the problem is I havn't any windows comp, so I can't launch this .exe file.

Is there any legal solution?