# How can I retrieve a .iso from an MSDN dreamspark account?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, boot-camp, msdn, dreamspark

I am currently attempting to bootcamp my Macbook Air. As far as I have seen, bootcamp can only be installed via .iso. When attempting to download my version of Windows (Win7 Pro 64-bit) from the dreamspark website, it prompts me to download the Secure Download Manager (SDL) and after that it asked me to download the .sdx file associated with this version of windows. After the .sdx file is downloaded, I have the opportunity to "Launch" the .sdx file from a button on the dreamspark website, but this appears to initiate an upgrade of the OS instantly. I am simply looking to download a .iso from dreamspark, as it seems that using just any version of Win7 pro 64bit (tried the generic installation disc .iso) to bootcamp will tell me that I have provided an invalid product key (I know for sure this product key is valid). Any ideas on how I can retrieve a .iso from this .sdx file or where I can find a downloadable win7 pro dreamspark .iso?

Comment: There exists a question on this website with every possible version of Windows 7 in an .iso format.  I would use that instead with your license.

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding. After you run the .sdx file through the SDL, does it convert into an iso after that?

Comment: Because I was unable to find a way to directly download the .iso. Only the .sdx.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/305431/where-can-i-download-windows-7-iso?rq=1

Comment: @Ramhound You're misunderstanding. I have tried the generic .iso for win7 64-bit. It does not work. I believe Dreamspark keys only work on products that have been installed using the Dreamspark .iso, which Addy2012 just provided me with a possible solution. I'm testing that out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDX file is just a small file containing download information for the Secure Download Manager.. Install the SDM first, and then click on the file to start the download process. Then you'll have your actual program ISO

Comment: Thanks so much, I thought .sdx was going to initiate an upgrade. I will give this a shot and report back shortly.

Comment: This provided me with the .iso. Thanks very much, did not realize that running the .sdx through the SDL was going to provide me with the proper format. :)